# Java checkbox from table validate for a button

Tags: java, swing

At the moment I have a `JTable` that has some `checkbox`, is there anyway for me to make a `Jbutton` that will check if the checkbox in the `Jtable` is checked or not.

So for example, if all my checkboxes are checked it will prompt Entry is save if not say check again.

Comment: This will come down to what type of `TableModel` you are using and the type of data you are storing in it, but basically, you want to iterate over all the rows of data in the `TableModel` and verify that the appropriate value/column is set

Comment: Atm i am using AbstractTableModel... not sure what u mean by iterate over all the rows of data. Ps.. still new to this

Comment: The TableModel represents the rows and columns of data which are presented in your table. Depending how you're managing this data will determine how you proceed